# How to set the DGL node features from networkx graph

Tags: python, networkx, directed-graph, pytorch-geometric, dgl

I'd like to convert the networkx graph to dgl data. 
But when I tried using `dgl.from_networkx` like tutorial, there was unexpected result.

```py
import dgl
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import torch

#Construct the networkx graph G containing three nodes, 2 undirected edges, 
#and three node attributes (i.e., 3-dimension of node features)
G = nx.Graph()

G.add_nodes_from([
    (1, {"x_0": 0.1, "x_1": 0.3, "x_2": 0.7}),
    (2, {"x_0": 0.1, "x_1": 0.3, "x_2": 0.7}),
    (3, {"x_0": 0.1, "x_1": 0.3, "x_2": 0.7}),
])

G.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (2, 1), (1, 3), (3,1)])

#Additionally, I add this code because the original dataset is called from .csv file.
#So, the below code means the list of features
#.csv file: node(row) x features(colum)
cols = list(["x_0", "x_1", "x_2"])

#Convert networkx from dgl
dgl_graph = dgl.from_networkx(G, node_attrs=cols)

#DGL Result
#Graph(num_nodes=3, num_edges=4,
#      ndata_schemes={'x_0': Scheme(shape=(), dtype=torch.float32), 'x_1': Scheme(shape=(), dtype=torch.float32), 'x_2': Scheme(shape=(), dtype=torch.float32)}
#      edata_schemes={})
```

When I run this in pytorch geometric, it returns what I think.

```py
from torch_geometric.utils.convert import from_networkx

pyg_graph = from_networkx(G, group_node_attrs=all)
pyg_graph

#PyG Result
#Data(edge_index=[2, 4], x=[3, 3])
```

Does DGL result has the same meaning with PyG result?
If not, how can I move the node attributes to DGL node feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does DGL result has the same meaning with PyG result? If not, how can I move the node attributes to DGL node feature?

DGL graphs are always directional, while `pyg_graph` will inherit properties from `G` (which is undirected). This can be verified via `pyg_graph.is_directed()`. This is why the number of edges in `dgl_graph` is 4, while the number of edges in the `pyg_graph` is 2 (the same as in `G`, can be seen via `len(G.edges())`). So, while both `dgl_graph` and `pyg_graph` have the same underlying network structure, if property of directed-ness matters in your workflow, then these graphs are not the same.

As regards the node attributes, they are already in the `dgl_graph`, you can view them using `dgl_graph.ndata`.